# How can I filter a Django Queryset on an extra field?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

Here is my Django model:

```
from django.db import models
class MyModel(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.IntegerField()
    c = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to retrieve all instances of this model in which `a = 5` and `b + c > 10`. How can I do it?

When I try this:

```
print MyModel.objects.filter(a=5).extra(
    select={"total_count": "b + c"},
    where=["total_count > 10"],
)
```

I get this error:

```
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'total_count' in 'where clause'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform `b + c > 10` to `b > 10 - c` and then use [F built-in function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)

```
MyModel.objects.filter(a=5).filter((b__gt=10-models.F('c'))
```

Using Django `extra()` is not quite safe

> You should be very careful whenever you use extra(). Every time you
>   use it, you should escape any parameters that the user can control by
>   using params in order to protect against SQL injection attacks .
>   Please read more about SQL injection protection.

Answer (score 1):

In django 1.7 this filter works fine and produces the following query:

```
SELECT (b + c) AS "total_count", "app_mymodel"."id", "app_mymodel"."a",
       "app_mymodel"."b", "app_mymodel"."c" 
FROM "app_mymodel"
WHERE ("app_mymodel"."a" = 5 AND (total_count > 10))
```

Can you copy your query with real field names?  May be you mistyped somewhere?